# Django models, @property decorator for method

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have model like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_route(self):
        ...
        return data
```

When I want to display value returned by `get_route()` in admin panel I have to create custom method like this:

```
def list_display_get_route(self, obj):
    return obj.get_route()
list_display = ('list_display_get_route', ...)
```

I've recently discovered that if I decorate `get_route()` with `@property` there's no need to use `list_display_get_route()` and the following will work:

**models.py**

```
@property
def get_route(self):
    ...
    return data
```

**admin.py**

```
list_display = ('get_route', ...)
```

Is this correct approach? Are there any drawbacks of this solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `get_route` in `list_display` should work even if you don't make it a property.

```
class Article(models.Model):

    def get_route(self):
        ...
        return data

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_route', ...)
```

See the [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) docs for the list of value types supported. The fourth example,  "a string representing an attribute on the model", is equivalent to your `get_route` method.

Using the `property` decorator is fine if you prefer, but in this case it would make more sense to name it `route`.

```
@property
def route(self):
    ...
    return data

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('route', ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your good explantation @Alasdair